# Future and reported speech

Tags: future-tense

When to use :

1 ) The weather report says it [will be] cloudy all day .

2 ) The weather report says it [is going to be]
cloudy all day .

3 ) The weather report says it [would be] cloudy all day .

4 ) The weather report says it [was going to be] cloudy all day .

Comment: Which one(s) do you think is/are correct, Why? Please read our [help center](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) :"Please make an effort to research your question before posting it, and be sure to add as much detail as you can when explaining your problem. The more you can tell us, the better answers you'll receive!"

Comment: Since more than one could be correct depending on context, you must add context. **Context is important**.

Answer (score 1):

Note in these cases "says" is present tense.  You are talking about what the report is telling you at the current moment.

> The weather report says it [will be] cloudy all day.
>
> The weather report says it [is going to be] cloudy all day.

Same thing.  Weather is being reported to you now, with a confident statement that there will be clouds all day.

It would be strange to say this after a certain arbitrary point in time (mid-day or so).  Because you are repeating the report's prediction in the present tense.  You'd have to change it for other uses, consider: *"The weather report **said** it **would** be cloudy all day...I guess they were right, as we can't see the sun setting due to the clouds."*

If a late-day weather report wants to discuss all-day cloudiness, they might say *"It will remain cloudy for the rest of the day."*  But you can't say "will be" or "going to" with "all day" in a future tense if a significant amount of the day has passed.

> The weather report says it [would be] cloudy all day.

Since we're talking on the present and saying "would be", that construction suggests "would be (if things were different)...but we are going to tell you why it won't actually be."

*"The weather report says 'it **would** be cloudy all day, but due to the cloud-sucking machines installed in the city last month, we're going to have sunny skies'."*

> The weather report says it [was going to be] cloudy all day.

Could be the same as "would be" but has a more likely tone of the report changing a previously expressed opinion; or otherwise reporting an unexpected change.

*"The weather report says it **was** going to be cloudy all day.  But the sun unexpectedly exploded...and burned up all the clouds.  We strive for accuracy in our forecasts, and apologize to our viewers."*